# oauthaccesstokens revokation/creation permission denied in OpenShift 4.6

Tags: openshift

When I used `oc get oauthaccesstokens`, I can get a list of active tokens, and I tried to use any of the tokens in that list to revoke itself or other tokens, none of them works; This works in the older OCP versions: 4.5/4.4/4.3, but does not work OCP 4.6

However, I can use the token that I get from the token request page, or `oc whoami -t`, to revoke other tokens, including itself. I will call this token - working token below.

I am not sure if it is an API change or a defect, but I do not see that in the openshift API page,

4.6: https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.6/rest_api/oauth_apis/oauthaccesstoken-oauth-openshift-io-v1.html
4.5: https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.5/rest_api/oauth_apis/oauthaccesstoken-oauth-openshift-io-v1.html

I found the following when I compare OCP 4.6 and 4.5:

1. **oauthaccesstokens** object are different in versions
2. the **oauthclient** are different in versions - although they are created by the same yaml file, the same code.
3. the working token (from request page or `oc whoami -t`) is not listed in `oc get oauthaccesstokens` in OCP 4.6, but listed in 4.5
4. the working token has the client name openshift-browser-client, but if I use a token with the same name from the token list i.e. `oc get oauthaccesstokens`, it does not have permission to revoke any of the tokens including iself in OCP 4.6.

Answer (score 0):

Probably my answer is not of interest for you anymore but oauthaccesstokens that don't start with sha256~ are deprecated since Openshift 4.6 apparently (noticed that from an alert in AlertManager). I believe it'll be removed in 4.8.